# Writing to ActiveRecord columns via numerical iteration

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra

I have a database that I want to store orders in. I don't want to bundle each line item together in one field unless there is a good reason to do so. With columns `item_1`, `item_2`, `item_3`, `item_4`; I want to loop through each line item until finished.

The error I get is:

> SyntaxError:
>   /Users/chadsakonchick/Projects/restlessnapkin/charge.rb:47: syntax
>   error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_end @order.line_item
>   = item["quantity"] 'x' item["item"] ^ /Users/chadsakonchick/Projects/restlessnapkin/charge.rb:47: syntax
>   error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end @order.line_item
>   = item["quantity"] 'x' item["item"] ^

`/order.rb`

```
# Write order to the database
@order = Order.new
@order.venue_id = @venue
@order.customer_id = @customer.id    

# Loop each line item
x = 1
@customer_order.each do |item|
  line_item = "item_#{x}"
  @order.line_item = item["quantity"] 'x' item["item"]
  x += 1
end
```

Comment: Is `@order.line_item` meant to be the string `"#{item["quantity"]} x #{item["item"]}"` or the number `item["quantity"] * item["item"]`?

Comment: I don't think you want to have a fixed number of line items either. Create a `LineItem` model and use an [association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) (`Order has_many :line_items` / `LineItem belongs_to :order`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

#### Creating the line item string

This raises a syntax error:

```
item["quantity"] 'x' item["item"]
```

Use string interpolation instead:

```
"#{item["quantity"]} x #{item["item"]}"
```

#### Assigning the string to an attribute

Your code assigns the string to `@order.line_item`, i.e. to a `line_item` attribute. The `line_item` *variable* is never used:

```
line_item = "item_#{x}"
@order.line_item = ...
```

Use [`ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods#[]=`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) instead:

```
line_item = "item_#{x}"
@order[line_item] = ...
```

You can get rid of the temporary variable `x` by using [`Enumerator#with_index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index):

```
@customer_order.each.with_index(1) do |item, index|
  @order["item_#{index}"] = "#{item["quantity"]} x #{item["item"]}"
end
```

Note that this will raise a `ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError` if there are more than 4 items, because there's no `item_5` attribute. So instead of having a fixed number of `item_x` attributes, you should create a separate `LineItem` model and set up an [association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html):

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items
end
```

This allows you to assign any number of line items. Assuming `LineItem` has attributes `position`, `quantity` and `item`, something like this would work:

```
@customer_order.each.with_index(1) do |item|
  @order.line_items.create(position: index, quantity: item['quantity'], item: item['item'])
end
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote you 100 times for all this fantastic advice. I've got everything working 100% and no limit on order line items. Thanks for the suggestion on decoupling the line_items from the order table, that was a lightbulb moment.